# Are flights more dangerous than bus rides?

Tags: health, buses, long-haul

It is usually known, that during long-haul flights some measurements must be taken to avoid veins clots. Eg.: stand up and walk once a while or take a antithrombotic shot before flight.

Yet I never heard of similar advice before long-haul bus rides, and they can take even longer (eg. bus from Buenos Aires to Lima takes 3 days).

Are flights more dangerous than bus rides, or are they equally risky?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are some [claims](http://www.globalchange.com/deepveinthrombosis.htm) (common but [contested](http://www.iasa.com.au/folders/Safety_Issues/Cabin_Safety/bloodclotted.html)) that the lower air pressure (and humidity) in a plane's cabin increases the risk of thrombosis.

Another factor is that buses usually have toilet breaks every couple of hours, which gives everyone an opportunity to stretch their legs - and people are more likely to make use of these opportunities than to do it regularly in a plane because there is more room and they're reminded and encouraged by the bus stopping and lots of others getting off.